# Android layouting with Relative Layout

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

could someone please explain me why the following snippet of code doesn't work as expected?
I cannot use the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` param for the first text view because doing so will put the view at the bottom of the whole screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:text="AT THE BOTTOM OF THE LAYOUT"/>


     <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_text_view"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:text="ABOVE THE PREVIOUS TEXT VIEW"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Eclipse says that the `@id/bottom_text_view` couldn't be resolved.

Please take in account that this example is a simplification of a real case where I want to put more complex views on top of a button i.e. a collapsible list view and a calendar in the following order:

- ListView
- Calendar
- Button

and I really need to collapse both the listview and the calendar and once done what remains visible should move in order to wrap to the content.

Please help with this stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Below there is my real case layout
The list view didn't take the space I want it to take.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/magnet_bkg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assets_header_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/view_padding"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/lbl_asset_manager_title"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/top_title_text_size"
        android:background="@drawable/dashboard_title_gradient_bg"
        android:visibility="visible"/>


    <!-- Use the linear layout in order to control the margins in 
    one place only -->
    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/assets_list_margin_side"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/assets_list_margin_side"
       android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/assets_list_margin_topbottom"
       android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/assets_list_margin_topbottom"
       android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The header with the asset information -->
        <include 
            layout="@layout/activity_magnet_enterprise_company_assets_list_item"/>

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/view_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_title_text_size"
            android:text="@string/lbl_report_filter_section_title"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:background="@color/color_title_bar"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/create_report_filter_bottom_margin"
            android:gravity="bottom">

           <!-- The generate report Button -->
           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/create_report_btn_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/filter_by_date_section_layout"
                android:background="@color/color_repoback_dark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/view_padding">

                <Button
                    style="@style/NormalButton"
                    android:onClick="onBtnCreateReportClick"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_button_create_report" />
            </LinearLayout> <!-- end of generate report Button layout -->


            <!-- The filter by date section -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/filter_by_date_section_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/filter_by_project_section_layout"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Sub header with the filter by date switch control -->

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/color_subtitle_bar"
                    android:padding="@dimen/view_padding_large" >

                    <Switch
                        android:id="@+id/filter_by_date_switch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/filter_by_date_switch"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_report_filter_by_date"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sub_title_text_size_small" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <!-- The section for date selection -->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/date_selection_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/color_repoback_dark"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/view_padding" >

                    <!-- Layout FROM date -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="@dimen/view_padding"
                            android:text="@string/lbl_report_date_from"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <DatePicker
                            android:id="@+id/from_date_report"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:calendarViewShown="false"
                            android:padding="@dimen/view_padding" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!-- Layout TO date -->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="@dimen/view_padding"
                            android:text="@string/lbl_report_date_to"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <DatePicker
                            android:id="@+id/to_date_report"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:calendarViewShown="false"
                            android:padding="@dimen/view_padding" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout> <!-- end of filter by date section layout -->

            <!-- The filter by project section -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/filter_by_project_section_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Sub header with the filter by project switch control -->

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/color_subtitle_bar"
                    android:padding="@dimen/view_padding_large" >

                    <Switch
                        android:id="@+id/filter_by_project_switch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/filter_by_project_switch"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="@string/lbl_report_filter_by_project"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sub_title_text_size_small" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <!-- The projects list view -->

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/projects_listview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/color_schedule_list_bg"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:divider="@color/color_lightgray"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="AT THE BOTTOM OF THE LAYOUT" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABOVE THE PREVIOUS TEXT VIEW" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: his problem was the relativelayout height was wrap_content which the layout will be at the top and not filling the parent !

Comment: This not is suitable for my case because as I said the real use case will let the list view to get all the available space this way. HEY wait a minute maybe It's worth a try...I'll let you know.

Comment: I tried the solution using a List view and it took all the space as I suspected. I'm going to edit my post in order to provide my real layout, hope you can help. Maybe I done some wrong

Answer (score 0):

its because you setting the `height` of the `RelativeLayout` as `wrap_content` 
copy this code after i change it a bit and see how it will work

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/bottom_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:text="AT THE BOTTOM OF THE LAYOUT"/>


     <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_text_view"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:text="ABOVE THE PREVIOUS TEXT VIEW"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but the result didn't change :(

Answer (score 0):

here is a layout i just created !

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Hi I'm The Text On TOP" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Hi I'm The Text Below the Text Above"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks again, but this won't work if the view put at the top is a space greedy one e.g. a ListView.